# How to use griddata() to transform the image, in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation

I have a 8-bit image and a transformation matrix. I need to use griddata() method **ONLY** to transform it?
I know how to do such translation by using affine2d() and imwarp() but, how to do this task using griddata()?

Comment: Any specific reason why you can only use `griddata`?

Comment: @NoelSegura, sounds like a homework type of question. Noname, please provide more information, sample data (small), sample transformation (simple), expected result etc ... read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for detail on how to ask a question with better chance of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get all the coordinates that you want to transform
2. Use the transform to get the warped coordinates
3. Sample the warped coordinates from the original coordinates using griddata

> ```
> % Params
> row = 10; % number of rows in the matrix
> col = 10; % number of cols in the matrix
> ficitoiusValues = rand(col,row);
>
> % Create a mash grid for all the coordinate in the matrix
> [Y,X] = meshgrid(1:col,1:row);
> corrdaintes = [X(:),Y(:), ones(row*col,1)];
>
> % Create a transform ( In your case you already have this)
> transform = rand(3,3);
>
> % Warp all the corrdiantes
> transformedCorrdaines = transform*corrdaintes';
>
> % Use griddata to find the new valiues of the new transformed corrdinates
> vq = griddata(1:col,1:row,ficitoiusValues,transformedCorrdaines(1,:),transformedCorrdaines(1,:));
> ```

Comment: Thanks.
Actually, I am new to MATLAB. I have a image (pentagon.tif). I have to transform it. How do I incorporate the image in the above code?

Comment: Read the image and for each channel of the image apply the code by replacing the ficitoiusValues by the channel. To get the row and col values just use [row,col]  =size(channel)